# What does mean that an ODE is analytic?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A friend of mine asked the following question:

Let $$y'' + p(z)y' + q(z)y = 0.$$

Show that this equations is not analytic on $\overline{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}.$

I am not able to solve once I don't know what the exercise is asking. Could someone explain to me?

Comment: Replace $y$ with $u(w)=y(1/z)$ to explore the regularity at $∞$.

Comment: @LutzL, thank you! I will think about it. But, from where this idea came?

Comment: Note that the question asks about the equation, not the solution? The only singular point could be $∞$. And even for the solution, by the Picard integral equation it is at least as smooth as the differential equation. Which again points to $z=∞$ as the only critical point.